# Plotly Express map - Understanding how colors are assigned based on data

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

Am using Plotly for the first time (https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.choropleth_mapbox.html).

I’ve put together a map of New York using a portion of the following data, and have added in County/FIPS information: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sobhanmoosavi/us-accidents

It is starting to take shape, so I have had a go at adding some color to it (see below).

[image: Progress so far]

```
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(data, geojson=counties, locations='FIPS', mapbox_style="open-street-map", color="Severity", zoom=6, center=dict(lat=42.8, lon=-75.3), height=800, width=1200, opacity=0.5)
fig.show()
```

I used a column called Severity to do this, which returns a number between 1 and 4.

I am trying to understand how the color has been assigned:

Pictured you can see that FIPS 36021 has a Severity of 4. If I look at the data for 36021, there are 279 rows with an average of 2.3 (there are 12 rows with a value of 1, 216 x 2, 7 x 3, and 44 x 4).

It seems like this should be showing a Severity of 2 - Can anyone shed some light on how this might be working?

I have tried adding something like color=np.median(data['Severity']) which I think would yield a better result, but it's not allowed...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: I downloaded the data from kaggle and checked the contents, but I don't see a 'FIPS' entry. Can you provide the full code including data extraction and processing?